# Count number of texts in which a word occurs

Tags: python, text, scikit-learn, word-frequency

I am building a word frequency, and relative frequency, list(s) for a collection of text files. Having discovered, by hand, that a couple of texts can overly influence the frequency of a word, one of the things I want to be able to do is count the number of times a word occurs. It strikes me that there are two ways to do this:

First, to compile a word frequency dictionary (as below -- and I'm not using the NLTK FreqDist because this code actually runs more quickly but if FreqDist has the above functionality built-in and I just didn't know it, I'll take it):

```
import nltk

tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')

freq_dic = {}
for text in ftexts:
    words = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
    for word in words:
        # form dictionary
        try: 
            freq_dic[word] += 1
        except: 
            freq_dic[word] = 1
```

From there, I assume I'll need to write another loop that uses the keys above as keywords:

```
# This is just scratch code
for text in ftexts:
    while True:
        if keyword not in line:
            continue
        else:
            break
    count = count + 1
```

And then I'll find some way to mesh these two dictionaries into a tuple or, possibly, a pandas dataframe by word, such that:

```
word1, frequency, # of texts in which it occurs
word2, frequency, # of texts in which it occurs
```

The other thing that occurred to me as I was writing this question was to use SciKit's term frequency matrix and then count rows in which a word occurs? Is that possible?

ADDED TO CLARIFY:

Imagine three sentences:
["I need to keep count of the children.",
 "If you want to know what the count is, just ask."
 "There is nothing here but chickens, chickens, chickens."]

"count" occurs 2x but is in two different texts; "chickens" occurs three times, but is in only one text. What I want is a report that looks like this:

```
WORD, FREQ, TEXTS
count, 2, 2
chicken, 3, 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-to-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Comment: Check out [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) which does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you, @VivekKumar. I fired up `sklearn` and I figured out what I needed.